# Android How can I call notifyDataSetChanged to refresh the list in AsyncTask onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, notifydatasetchanged

I have a list view populated with a database, with a custom cursor adapter, SavedTripsAdapter.

Here is how I initialized the adapter:
    allTrips = mDb.fetchAllTrips();

```
        String[] from = new String[] { "purp", "fancystart", "fancyinfo", "endtime", "start", "distance", "status" };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.TextViewPurpose, R.id.TextViewStart,
                R.id.TextViewInfo };

        sta = new SavedTripsAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.saved_trips_list_item, allTrips, from, to,
                CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

        lv.setAdapter(sta);
```

When I click on a list item, I can upload it again by calling this following function, which is completed in an AsyncTask.

In FragmentSavedTripsSection:

```
private void retryTripUpload(long tripId) {
    TripUploader uploader = new TripUploader(getActivity());
    uploader.execute();
}
```

In TripUploader:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    try {
        if (result) {
            Toast.makeText(mCtx.getApplicationContext(),"Trip uploaded successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mCtx.getApplicationContext(),"Cycle Atlanta couldn't upload the trip, and will retry when your next trip is completed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Just don't toast if the view has gone out of context
    }
}
```

However, the TripUploader is a separate class. When the trip is uploaded successfully, the database is updated, so I want to refresh the list using savedTripsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Where and how should put savedTripsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()?

If I put it in the list view class, it is not called onPostExecute. But if I put it in the TripUploader's onPostExecute function, how can I get access to the same instance of savedTripsAdapter, which I instantiated in the list view class?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you setting the adapter on Lsitview in FragmentSavedTripsSection class?

Comment: @amitsingh I added some code. Thanks!

Comment: makle a "public" function in "FragmentSavedTripsSection" class for notifying the adapter and call that function from the onPostExecute() of your AsyncTask.

Comment: @amitsingh I added: public void notifyDataSetChanged(){
  sta.notifyDataSetChanged();
 } How should I call the function from onPostExecute()?

Comment: access it with the object of that class by sending it in the constructor of your TripUploader class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical usage of `notifyDataSetChanged()` is to call it in the same class that handles your views.

For example, in your `Fragment's` `onViewCreated()`, you get a reference to the `ListView` and the adapter, and when you have your data ready, typically in the `onPostExecute()` you would call  `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update the view.

If you prefer to pass your adapter to another object to do the data manipulation, you can just go ahead and do it, nothing special since java passes object by reference, so your Adapter object will be the same object in both classes

Edit:

My assumptions are:

- your Adapter is called `sta`
- your Fragment is called `FragmentSavedTrips`
- your object that modifies the data is call `SavedTripsChanger`
- your data string array is called from.

Inside `SavedTripsChanger` have a private variable to hold the adapter

> private SavedTripsAdapter mSavedTripsAdapter;

and a setter method (optional getter method)

```
public SavedTripsAdapter setSavedTripsAdapter(SavedTripsAdapter mSavedTripsAdapter) {
     this.mSavedTripsAdapter = mSavedTripsAdapter;
}
```

When you create object `SavedTripsChanger` pass it the mSavedTripsAdapter instance, either in the constructor or using the setter method. Inside `FragmentSavedTrips`

```
SavedTripsChanger mSavedTripsChanger = new SavedTripsChanger();
mSavedTripsChanger.setSavedTripsAdapter(sta);
```

now you are ready to use it. After you are done modifying the data and ready to update the view inside `SavedTripsChanger` just call the `notifyDataSetChanged()`

> mSavedTripsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: When the user choose a row, it will trigger a trip to be uploaded to a database. This operation is triggered in several places so I have to make it a separated class. Would you please provide more details for how to pass the adapter? Thanks!

Comment: I added the code, and I successfully passed the mSavedTripsAdapter, but why the list is not updated by mSavedTripsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();?

Comment: Are you sure that your data has changed? I assume that your data is stored in allTrips, is that a native variable or an object?

Comment: It is an object. In another function, it is using listSavedTrips.invalidate();
  populateList(listSavedTrips); to update the list. If I want to do this, what code should I use?

Comment: I think the data is changed because when I kill the app and open again, it is the right.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TripUploader extends AsyncTask<>{
    private listener;

    public interface YourListener{
       onCompleted(boolean result);
    }

    public TripUploader(YourListener listener){
       this.listener = listener;
    }

    protected onPostExecute(boolean result){
       listener.onCompleted(result);
    }
}
```

in your main class, implement this listener and implement the method, so whenever your asynctask finish, you'll receive it and you can make notifydatasetchange inside your class.

```
public class FragmentSavedTripsSection extends Fragment implements YourListener{

  public void onCompleted(boolean result){
       // notify data
  }
}
```

By using interface, you can use this class for other activities as well without coupling it to only one class.

Comment: Where should I put each of the code? I am a little bit confusing;)

Comment: edited my answer, it should be more clear to you now

Comment: I added the code, but I can't do public class FragmentSavedTripsSection extends Fragment implements YourListener{.